# Microsoft SQL Server : error while connecting to local server

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Whenever I'm trying to connect SSMS to my computer I get this error:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to NUNA.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
>
> The system cannot find the file specified

I'm  pretty sure that my computer or server is name is `NUNA` but it doesn't  connect and I get this error. I have tried to stop SQL Server Express in Windows Services, but it doesn't show the SQL Server Express

[image]

Comment: If you've installed SQL Server **Express** locally and used all the defaults during install, you need to use `NUNA\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as the server/instance name when trying to connect

Comment: Perhaps you only installed SSMS - which is a completely separate download/install than one of the various editions of the SQL Server database engine. If so, you will need to install a database engine.

Comment: mar_s Thank You it fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you try restart SQL Server service or try with "."?

Comment: Yes But it doesn't effect  anything